# index of closed homotopic curves

Tags: complex-analysis

Can we claim that two homotopic closed continuous curves in the complex plane have the same winding number with respect to every point not belonging to their graph? I guess we can't, since two concentric circles and a point in the annulus give a counterexample. What hypothesis should be added?

Comment: I don't think this quite the right statement. Over a domain $\Omega$ with $x\in \Omega^c$ two curves homotopic in $\Omega$ have the same winding number around each $x$. Is that what you are looking for? One can prove this rather directly from the residue theorem and the Cauchy integral theorem for homotopic curves.

Comment: I don't have the hypothesis of a domain, I'm sure of this... actually, if I take the cue from you, do you think that adding the following hypothesis: "the curves are homotopic on the complex plane removed of the point" then they have the same winding number with respect to that point. In addition, the converse seems to be also true: if they have the same winding number with respect to a point, then they are homotopic on the complex plane removed of that point.